# Squared Frobenius norm and orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, orthogonal-matrices, matrix-norms

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ be any matrices and let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times l}$ such that $l \leq d$, and $X^{T}X = I_{l \times l}$ where $I_{l \times l}$ is the identity matrix in the space $\mathbb{R}^{l \times l}$. ($X$ is a matrix with orthogonal columns, a.k.a, none square orthogonal matrix)

My aim is to show that
$$ 
\left\| AX\right\|_F^2 \leq \left\| BX\right\|_F^2 + \left\| (A-B)X\right\|_F^2
$$

Is right to assume that such inequality holds? How can I prove its correctness?

Comment: I think you meant to write that $X^TX = I_{l \times l}$

Comment: Thanks, i have edited the question accordingly :)

Comment: It's easy to show that this holds without the $2$s, but I'm not sure about your result.

Comment: without the squared, using the traingle inequality, one can prove the correctness of the inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality will not hold in general.

Define $\langle A,B\rangle = \operatorname{tr}(AB^T)$, so that $\|A\|^2 = \langle A,A\rangle$.  We have
$$
\begin{align*}
\|AX\|^2 &= \langle BX + (A-B)X, BX + (A-B)X\rangle
\\ &= \langle BX , BX \rangle + \langle (A-B)X, (A-B)X \rangle + 2 \langle BX, (A-B)X \rangle
\\ & = \|BX\|^2 + \|(A-B)X\|^2 + 2 \operatorname{tr}(BX [(A-B)X]^T)
\end{align*}
$$
So, your inequality holds if and only if $\operatorname{tr}(BX [(A-B)X]^T) \leq 0$, which won't be true for arbitrary matrices $A,B$.

To more intuitively understand the trace expression, it may help to rewrite it as
$$
\operatorname{tr}(BX [(A-B)X]^T)  = \operatorname{tr}(X^T[(A-B)^TB]X)
$$
or as

$$
\operatorname{tr}(BX [(A-B)X]^T)  = \langle (A-B)^TB,XX^T \rangle
$$

Comment: I think you mean it will hold when the trace expression is lower or equal to zero, right?

Comment: Right, good catch